# Splunk's 'Search-Time Field Extraction' Open-Source Alternative

Tags: open-source, search-engine

I'm looking for an open-source alternative to Splunk - specifically *Search-Time Field Extraction* feature which [isn't possible in Elasticsearch](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dynamic-field-creation-using-regex-and-scripted-fields/312/2).  Also looking for that [feature to exist as a RegEx query](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.1/Knowledge/Configureadvancedextractionswithfieldtransforms#REGEX).  Reindexing data to add additional fields just isn't scalable.

Any suggestions?